# trigger apple script alert when opening program

Tags: applescript

I´d like to have an alert shown when opening a program (reminding me to attach an external thumb drive as dongle without the program would not work otherwise).

Ideally, the script would "monitor" the Application folder so that I can use the usual application icon rather than clicking a special script link (because other family members use the computer as well).

Also, using apple script would be simple I think, as it is there already. I have figured out how to show the alert:

```
    on open "/Applications/MaxQDA.app/"

    set theAlertText to "alert text."

    set theAlertMessage to "subtext"


    display alert theAlertText message theAlertMessage as 
    critical buttons {"stop", "go"} default button "go" cancel button "stop"

    --> Result: {button returned:"go"}

    delay 1

    end open

   delay 1

   end open
```

What I am not sure about is 
a) how to have the application monitored or if this is possible at all
b) how to let the script decide if the application is starting through or not: can the script "hold" the starting process until I click the "go-button" on the alert window
c) where to integrate this script in my system.

Many thanks for all hints!

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `on open "/Applications/MaxQDA.app/"` cannot work.

The handler can only be used to respond to dropped items.

The easiest solution is indeed to write a script which manages the dongle stuff and then launches the target application. Save the script as application with the same icon as the target application and place it in the dock.

Comment: ok, thanks, that´s a clever idea. Will the rest of the script work as intended or any hints on the sample that I sent?

Comment: You won't need the delay lines